# Can the Bessel functions tend to a plane wave?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions

Can the Bessel functions tend to a plane wave?
If I have this function:

$$
y(u)= c_1J_{-\sqrt{b}/2}(e^{2u}/6)+c_2J_{\sqrt{b}/2}(e^{2u}/6)+c_1J_{-i\sqrt{b}/2}(e^{2u}/6)+c_2J_{i\sqrt{b}/2}(e^{2u}/6)
$$

with b a positive number, for $u \rightarrow - \infty$ I find an exponential behaviour using Mathematica with "Series[]". But I don't know how to move on and how to collect together the same kind of exponential. May you help me?

Comment: Simply use the asymptotics of the Bessel functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms , just taking care of whether $\sqrt{b}/2$ is integer or not. By the way, these are NOT plane waves, since $u$ is real, you get "waves" (trigonometric functions) in the opposite limit.

Comment: @DanielCastro thanks! But in this case, $\sqrt{b}/2$ isn't an integer and in your link only negative and positive integer are cited

Comment: of course not, the very first formula says very clearly that $J_\alpha(z)\propto z^\alpha$ for $z\ll1$, and similarly when the index is imaginary (you can derive this formula directly from the Bessel equation). You can consult Gradshteyn and Ryzhik for an extensive catalog of properties of special functions. I don't think this is the appropriate place for this question.